# The same function behaves differently, why?

Tags: matlab, function, figure

I have this function below which works perfecttly as I need:

```
function [pointsQRS, pointsP, pointsT] = VCG (pointsQRS,pointsP,pointsT)


 global ax1 ax2 h

 figure('Name','Vektorkardiogram','NumberTitle','off','Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8])

 %% first axes

 ax1=subplot(1,2,1);

 set(ax1,'Position',[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.7])

 title('Vektorkardiogram')
 hold on
 grid on
 axis vis3d

 view([0 10])

 plotCurve

 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

 text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
 text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
 text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);


 %% second axes

 ax2=subplot(1,2,2);

 set(ax2,'Position',[0.6,0.2,0.3,0.7])

 title('Vektorkardiogram')
 hold on
 grid on
 axis vis3d

 view([10 10])

 plotCurve

     function plotCurve

         for i=2:size(pointsQRS,1)
             if mod(i,2)==0
                 QRS=plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'-g','LineWidth',1);
             else
                 plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
             end
         end


         for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
             if mod(i,2)==0
                 T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-
1:i],3),'-r','LineWidth',1);
             else
                 plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-
1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
             end
         end

         for i=2:size(pointsP,1)
             if mod(i,2)==0
                 P=plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-
1:i],3),'-b','LineWidth',1);
             else
                 plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-
1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
             end
         end

         xlabel('Vx');ylabel('Vy');zlabel('Vz');

     end


 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

 text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
 text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
 text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);





 %% Slider Rotace

 S = uicontrol('Style','slider',...
     'Position',[10 10 300 20],...
     'Max',180,...
     'Min',-180,...
     'Value',0,...
     'SliderStep',[1/360 1/360]);

 LS=addlistener(S,'ContinuousValueChange',@slider_callback);
 set(S,'UserData',LS)

 end



 function slider_callback(hObject,eventData)

 global ax1 ax2 

 val = get(hObject,'value');

 view(ax1,[val,10])
 view(ax2,[val+10,10])

 end
```

But when I changed the code, simplified, because in other function I need only *pointsT* it gives me the error as in the picture.
The simplified code is:

```
function pointsT = VCG_T (pointsT)


 global ax1_T ax2_T h_T

 figure('Name','Vektorkardiogram','NumberTitle','off','Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8])

 %% first axes

 ax1_T=subplot(1,2,1);

 set(ax1_T,'Position',[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.7])

 title('Vektorkardiogram')
 hold on
 grid on
 axis vis3d

 view([0 10])

 plotCurve




 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

 text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
 text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
 text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);


 %% second axes

 ax2_T=subplot(1,2,2);

 set(ax2_T,'Position',[0.6,0.2,0.3,0.7])

 title('Vektorkardiogram')
 hold on
 grid on
 axis vis3d

 view([10 10])

 plotCurve




         for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
             if mod(i,2)==0
                 T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-
 1:i],3),'-r','LineWidth',1);
             else
                 plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-
1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
             end
         end



 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

 text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
 text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
 text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);



 %% Slider Rotace

 S = uicontrol('Style','slider',...
     'Position',[10 10 300 20],...
     'Max',180,...
     'Min',-180,...
     'Value',0,...
     'SliderStep',[1/360 1/360]);

 LS=addlistener(S,'ContinuousValueChange',@slider_callback);
 set(S,'UserData',LS)

 end



 function slider_callback(hObject,eventData)

 global ax1_T ax2_T 

 val = get(hObject,'value');

 view(ax1_T,[val,10])
 view(ax2_T,[val+10,10])

 end
```

The picture of the error:
[image]

I have literally no idea why the simplified code doesn't work, probably I'm overlooking some thing.
Could you please give me a hint?

New problem below:
[image]

Comment: in the first function there's a subfunction called `plotCurve` which is missing from the second (simplified) function. just add `plotCurve` definition to your simplified function.

Comment: I apologize for this stupid question in advance, could you please write me what I must put and where? I have been trying to figure it out for last 30 minutes the thing you just wrote me, but I still don't see the missing thing from the functional function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed the line `function plotCurve`. This is an important one since it defines a local function that the main function `VCG` calls. In your reduced example this function does not exist anymore since you removed its header. That's why you see this error.

Just put it back (before the first loop), then it should work.

Comment: I apologize for this stupid question in advance, could you please write me what I must put and where?
I have been trying to figure it out for last 30 minutes the thing you just wrote me, but I still don't see the missing thing from the functional function.

Comment: You make a line with only `function plotCurve` on it and place it in front of the first `for` loop (`for i=2:size(pointsT,1)`).

Comment: Yep, now I can see that, but after doing it, a different problem occurs, it's in the edited question.
Do you know why is it doing the other problem?

Comment: Every function needs a corresponding `end`. You also lost that one. Put a line with only `end` on it after the loop.